# window.addEventListener("load",function(){}); does not work

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, onload

I'm struggling around with a weird problem that shouldn't be too difficult. On every new link that's clicked, I want JS to append a string the the URL. Something like `name=MYNAME`. Unfortunately it does not work. The event does not get fired at all. Why?

I also tried working with `window.onload = myFunction;` but it refreshes my url endless of times.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you change URL by setting location.href, then page will refresh endlessly, it is inevitable.

Comment: can I change it somehow else or stop it from refreshing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my own problem. Hope my solution helps the ones still looking for one!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");

        var character = "";
        if (href.indexOf("?") != -1) {
            character = "&";
        } else {
            character = "?";
        }

        var additionalParams = "name=<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>&qwer=<?php echo $_GET['qwer']; ?>";

        var url = href + character + additionalParams;
        $(this).attr("href",url);
    });
});
</script>
```

I simply parsed the `URL` out of the selected `<a>` field, edited that `url with my parameters` and put it back into its `href-attribute`.

There you go, works like a charm in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using JQuery?

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Money?</a>

$(function(){
    // opens a new window to do a Google search for MONEY!!
    $("a").click(function(){
        window.open($(this).attr("href") + "/search?q=is+there+money+in+the+banana+stand");
    });
});
```

If you don't want a new window change `window.open` to `window.location = $(this).attr...etc`.

Comment: how can I be so blind?! O: Thanks [:

Comment: I tried it like you said but it didnt put in the new parameters

Answer (score 0):

**JAVASCRIPT PURE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

//// WORK JS EXAMPLE

};
</script>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//// WORK JS EXAMPLE

});
</script>
```